# Difference between Solaris and POSIX

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, solaris

Is implementation of Solaris functions and POSIX ones similar or diverge alot. Actually, I was trying to find a solution for forking a process with multiple threads. POSIX doesn't have any function to do this while Solaris has **forkall** for this purpose. Do you think it can be easily ported to Linux. Note that my solution does not need to be portable or POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Solaris has a full set of POSIX interfaces (possible without some optional parts), But Solaris has extra interfaces to support older Solaris software (which was written not with POSIX but with Solaris interfaces).

Also, there is a thread in ML about forkall http://www.mail-archive.com/opensolaris-code@opensolaris.org/msg02256.html

> Solaris supports POSIX (among a number
>   of other standards), but not all
>   things you'll find on Solaris are
>   *strictly* POSIX.

The porting of such internal thing (process/thread management are deeply in-kernel) is hard and almost equal to writing this from  Scratch. This is also because Solaris uses different model of threads.

Comment: Do you know the equivalent of glibc for Solaris, so that I can have a peek at the fork and forkall code there?

Comment: forkall and fork are kernel calls (syscalls, system calls). They are in kernel, not in libc. Libc will contain only wrapper to do a syscall and may be some additional utility. Here is a forkall in OpenSolaris kernel: http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/common/os/fork.c?v=OPENSOLARIS#L107  Here is the wrapper in OpenSolaris libc http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/lib/libc/port/threads/scalls.c#280

Comment: Ah, very true, I forgot that. Thanks for reminding me and providing me the link :)!

Comment: Actually, opensolaris libc stops the threads before doing a forkall: this function is called just before syscall: http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/lib/libc/port/threads/thr.c#suspend_fork Stopping is done via `lwp_suspend` syscall: http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/uts/common/os/lwp.c#1088 I can't remember anything like this in Linux in 30 seconds.

Comment: Loop of thread (LWP) cloning (in-kernel): http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/common/os/fork.c?v=OPENSOLARIS#L380

Comment: Thanks osgx! The information you are providing is very useful. I have one more question, which is that how can I introduce my forkall function without rewriting the kernel. I can't modify the kernel, because I will be running my programs on a computer on which I have no administrative rights. Is it possible to do this with a kernel module?

Comment: Kernel module is almost the same as `modify the kernel`, because you need `administrative rights` to load module. Loaded module can change anything in kernel and|or give you an  `administrative rights`.

Comment: Thats good! Yes I know it takes administrative rights to load a kernel, but one can ask the administrator to load a kernel once, but ofcourse he won't accept a demand to put the modified kernel :)!

Comment: It is harder to do this in module, but possible. To do a kernel development, you can set up an `qemu` and load any kernel into it. It will emulate the CPU, also it has good and easy interfaces to debuggers (no more com2com long wires and second PC for debugging a kernel).